# Memory issue in ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using UINavigationcontroller as root view controller. I am new to iphone ARC and sqlite operations under ARC.

1. My rootviewcontroller is loginviewcontroller next is homeview which contains scrollView with 4 UIviewcontroller in it.
2. I am using Instruments to test as I am getting a memory warning. After using my app for about 5-10 minutes, when I logout (for this I am using popToRootViewController) and login again Live Bytes goes on increasing and when I check Call Trees -

   ```
    [NSObject(NSTreadPerformAdditions) performselectorOnMainThread:withObject:waituntilDone:]
   ```

shows **15.91MB Bytes** used and following it shows

I am also doing SQLite operations and upon performing those operations, it adds around

if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String],&dBObject)!= SQLITE_OK)

shows **10MB Live Bytes** for opendatabase, selectquery and update

For the first time I tested my app using Instruments, it showed the following:
[image]

How can i release this memory now?

**EDIT:**

i am using this code for retriving data

```
-(int)CheckCompanyIsAvailableInTradeList:(NSString *)CompanyId UserId:(NSString *)userId
{
int check=0;
if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &dBObject) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *sqlStatement =NULL;
    sqlStatement = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tradelist WHERE compnyID = '%@' and UserMasterID ='%@' ;",CompanyId,userId];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dBObject, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                check = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

            }
        }



    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

}
sqlite3_close(dBObject);
return check;

}
```

> whenever this method is called live bytes goes on increasing
>   continously

Comment: Are you calling `sqlite3_close(dbObject)` after you complete an operation on DB?

Comment: Thanks for Reply yes i have done that

Comment: Can you add one of the function code in your question?

Comment: check i have given snippet

Comment: Are you calling any of the db functions in a loop/recursion? If that is the case, try not to open and close connection everytime, instead keep the connection open until recursion is over and then close it.

Comment: Thanks for it. Yes i am calling funcation  in a loop. i will do neccary changes and let you know.. what about the first screen shot presented that shows 15.91MB

Comment: Still the memory goes on increasing with every operation

Comment: I'm not sure this will have an effect since you close the database afterwards, but you might try setting the cache size for SQLite to it's minimum so it doesn't use much memory: `const char *pragmaSql = "PRAGMA cache_size = 0"; sqlite3_exec(database, pragmaSql, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Ok will try that and let you know about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Before you start your loop you have to open database...

and after completing you have to close your database..

e.g.

```
 -(void)downloadData
 {
 [self  openDB];// database is open..

 // start your loop 
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
   [self executeInsertQuery];

}

[self  closeDb]; 
 }


-(void)openDB
{
 if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String],&dBObject)!= SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(dBObject);
}

} 


-(void)closeDb
{
if (dBObject)
{

    int rc = sqlite3_close(dBObject);
    NSLog(@"close rc=%d", rc);

    if (rc == SQLITE_BUSY)
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        while ((stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(dBObject, 0x00)) != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"finalizing stmt");
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }

        rc = sqlite3_close(dBObject);
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"close not OK.  rc=%d", rc);
    }

    dBObject = NULL;
}

}

  -(Bool)executeInsertQuery
{


  NSString* strQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Insert into   list(compnyID,UserMasterID) values('%@','%@');",companyId ,userId ];

 char *err;
if (sqlite3_exec(dBObject, [queryString UTF8String], NULL,NULL, &err)!= SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(dBObject);
    return NO;
}
else
{
    return YES;
}


}
```

Comment: thats working for me.. Thanks i had lot of headache because of this